# Lat/Long attribute to Trimble Pathfinder Data Dictionary

Tags: data, trimble, pathfinder, dictionary

Is it possible to add beginning and end point lat/long attribute to Trimble Pathfinder Data Dictionary before collecting data in the field?

Comment: While it's entirely possible you might get a response/solution here, I would also suggest http://surveyorconnect.com/ as a resource.